# What is the <meta name="viewport"> tag?

Tags: html, viewport, meta-tags

What is

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
```

Like part by party I want to learn HTML and am using a webpage from a club I joined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag has the answer already.

Comment: To most people all you really know is that it makes the web page responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp):

> HTML5 introduced a method to let web designers take control over the
> viewport, through the  tag.
>
> You should include the following  viewport element in all your
> web pages:
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
> This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's
> dimensions and scaling.
>
> The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the
> screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page
> is first loaded by the browser.

About the meta tag [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp):

> The `<meta>` tag defines metadata about an HTML document. Metadata is
> data (information) about data.
>
> `<meta>` tags always go inside the  element, and are typically
> used to specify character set, page description, keywords, author of
> the document, and viewport settings.
>
> Metadata will not be displayed on the page, but is machine parsable.
>
> Metadata is used by browsers (how to display content or reload page),
> search engines (keywords), and other web services.
>
> There is a method to let web designers take control over the viewport
> (the user's visible area of a web page), through the  tag (See
> "Setting The Viewport" example below).

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if there's anything webby that I want to know more about, I can add the word "**mdn**" to my web searches, and that usually moves the 'mozilla developer network' web site to the top. In this case, searching google for "mdn viewport meta" brings me to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag which answers your question very well.

P.S. Thanks! I hadn't known what that was either!

Answer (score 0):

From the  [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

> The browser's viewport is the area of the window in which web content can be seen.

The `width` property controls the size of the viewport
The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded.

**Note:Always read the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) for more info about any concept you find difficult to understand**